# My Plymouth boot splash blinks and glitches. How can I fix it?

Tags: linux, boot, grub, arch-linux

I have recently installed Plymouth in my Arch machine. I've configured my GRUB kernel params so that I don't get bothered with unnecessary messages (if I have any problem, I tend to read my logs).

My problem is that whenever my boot animation appears on my screen, a blinking cursor appears on the top left corner of my screen. At a certain moment, everything turns black (from my gray, Arch logo screen) and the logo appears, followed by other graphical elements (in my case, some blinking stars around it).

This produces a black screen with flying gray squares with stars and the Arch Linux logo, which keeps on showing until I get to the login screen. I have seen on some videos this shouldn't be happening. Has anybody experienced the same?

Answer (score 0):

The cursor can be removed by adding the kernel parameter `vt.global_cursor_default=0` as explained [here](http://www.friendlyarm.net/forum/topic/2998). Considering the strange artifacts in the logo, that is probably a broken Plymouth theme. Read [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Plymouth) article, especially the section on "Changing the theme", and possibly install a clean version of the your theme.

Comment: The theme is the _fade-in_ one. It should work well, as it came by default.